# How do you check if a string exist in a constant

Tags: c#, .net

Please don't tell me to use enum instead.  How do I check if "testStr" is in the struct "Supplier"?

```
public struct Supplier {
    public const string
        NA = "N/A",
        companyA = "companyA",
        companyB = "companyB";
}

string testStr = "companyA";
```

Comment: What do you actually want to achieve here?

Comment: Do you mean one of the **property values** (`Supplier` class) equals to the `testStr` constant?

Comment: When you say `constant` in the question do you mean property of a structure? What do you mean?

Comment: Is "any" in "companyB" by your reckoning?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This can be achieved via reflection:

```
void Main()
{
  // make sure that we only take public static const
  string phrase = "companyA";
  var fields = typeof(Supplier).GetFields(BindingFlags.Static | BindingFlags.Public).Where(i => i.IsLiteral);
  foreach (FieldInfo field in fields)
  {
    string val = field.GetRawConstantValue().ToString();
    string msg = string.Format("is '{0}' equal to '{1}' => {2}", val, phrase, val == phrase);
    Console.WriteLine(msg);
  }
}

// Define other methods and classes here
public struct Supplier {
    public const string
        NA = "N/A",
        companyA = "companyA",
        companyB = "companyB";
};
```

Answer (score 2):

This should do it

```
  string toSearch = "companyA";
            var hasField = typeof(Supplier).GetFields(BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Static).
                Select(x => x.GetRawConstantValue().ToString()).Contains(toSearch);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can construct an array, and use LINQ to search it:

```
if (new[] {Supplier.NA, Supplier.companyA, Supplier.companyB}.Contains(testStr)) {
    ...
}
```

On a side note, I assume that you realize that the way the `struct Supplier` is defined is highly unorthodox (that's the most polite way of putting it), because it does not have fields, only constants.

Comment: What is the "orthodox" way of defining it?  I am kind of using it like a dropdownlist possible values.

Comment: @YongkeBillYu A more typical way of handling user-visible string constants is a combination of `enum`s and either resource files or custom attributes that pair up a constant with a user-visible string.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use reflextion to retrieve member names of a struct.
It is quite easy:

```
using System.Reflextion;

static void Main()
{
    if (MemberExists(typeof(Supplier), testStr))
        Console.WriteLine(testStr + " exists in Supplier");
    else
        Console.WriteLine(testStr + " does not exists in Supplier");
}

public bool MemberExists(Type structure, string name)
{
    foreach(MemberInfo member in structure.GetMembers())
        if (member.Name == name) return true;
    return false;
}
```

Hope this will help you, as you can see from a different answer there are a lot of options avaliable in reflextions.

Answer (score 0):

Although this does not answer your question per se but I started with a similar idea as yours but shifted it to something else. Reflection is kind of slower than what you might want (at least for me) so instead of using reflection to solve my problem I reverted the original struct to a List of strings (or array of strings if the number of values is constant) and used the Contains extension method.

It is a simple one liner. It simplifies your search code while not increase your memory consumption, nor your complexity (and according to my calculations it's faster than using reflection).

So basically your enum will have an array of three strings. You need to remember which is which in the array and then just call `Array.Contains` method to check if the string you have exists in that array